# Why is a MySql Table name case-sensitive?

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm dealing with MySql and ASP.CS (C#). When I went to MySql and created a database table with the name `ABC_XYZ,` it was created, and when I tried to create `abc_xyz` it was also created. I don't know why this happened.

Please help me figure out how to handle this issue; since some people will write the table name in lowercase and others in uppercase, this can be an issue in the future.

Thanks.

Comment: I think it depends on your operating system, because MySQL creates files for the tables. You can get into a huge mess, so avoid those conflicts whenever possible!

Comment: what is your collation set to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior is dependent on the Operating System (case sensitivity of the file system), and the setting of the **`lower_case_table_names`** variable.

This behavior is documented in the MySQL Reference Manual:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

---

One brief excerpt:

Best practice is "to adopt a consistent convention, such as always creating and referring to databases and tables using **lowercase** names. This convention is recommended for maximum portability and ease of use."